# Retrieve HTML content refreshed with Ajax

Tags: java, html, ajax

I tried to get HTML content from a website and I did it with this code.

```
public void extractRoutes(String urlStringifyed) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    URL url = new URL(urlStringifyed);
    URLConnection c = url.openConnection();
    c.connect();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    String line = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
}
```

Now I want to get the content from a specific page that is loaded with Ajax and protected with ReChapta, but I can't.

Below is the url. I'm passing all the arguments, but the content that I get from this link says to me that the service is temporally down and I should try later. The thing that I don't understand is that when I copy the url and paste in my browser, it works fine. The second link that does not involve rechapta shouts the same thing.

```
https://mersultrenurilor.infofer.ro/ro-RO/Itineraries?DepartureStationName=Ia%C8%99i&ArrivalStationName=Suceava&DepartureDate=21.01.2019&TimeSelectionId=0&MinutesInDay=0&ChangeStationName=&DepartureTrainRunningNumber=&ArrivalTrainRunningNumber=&ConnectionsTypeId=0&OrderingTypeId=0&g-recaptcha-response=03AO9ZY1ChGhLCoSKCnF49dyCskHENK7ZUYdJEK_UCDVPn7RYGp40CMRUxvA0Q_ni6fDhP9BRm6viymicOOudd78WJbaHb2vbbtCq0DLS7NzngWBAgBKaWBFBa94RKqetwMSR89p5G1a8oS3bknB6d2tyZ2zhUk1veesR2Ef-RNVXDMpy0GotKH_XGPylDTvL5ftIrDem1LmWb4lQYNY0CCJ7jFScQf6SRqSH18jBWHAGEXVSlsQjoK8X4Q6riSlo1LK_vMJR-F-HVig7vavBd6zTI6LjceGyBtlQZCK7tcIuj4cS9Yg-tMbRKn_laukwLkceOpN8Q88_Aafz9JPtyx-eJAN_5fMbuRw

http://mersultrenurilor.infofer.ro/ro-RO/Itineraries?DepartureStationName=Ia%C8%99i&ArrivalStationName=Suceava&DepartureDate=21.01.2019%200%3A00%3A00&AreOnlyTrainsWithReservation=False&ArrivalTrainRunningNumber=&DepartureTrainRunningNumber=&ConnectionsTypeId=0&MinutesInDay=0&OrderingTypeId=0&TimeSelectionId=0&ChangeStationName=&IsSearchWanted=False
```

How I can get html content(I'm interested in train routes that are showed) from this loaded url?